# Jenkins piepleine with dir correct syntax

Tags: jenkins

Hi guys I'm trying to write a jenkins pipeline with change dir, I can't get the syntax right, can anyone help me fix this?

the documentation is kinda unclear on where should I put this

```
   pipeline {
            agent {
                docker {
                    image 'node' 
                    args '-p 5000:5000' 
                }
            }
            stages {
                dir("Backend") {
                stage('build') {
                        steps {
                                sh 'pwd'
                                sh 'echo start build'
                                sh 'ls'
                                sh 'npm install'
                            }
                     }
                }
                dir("Backend") {
                  stage('Test') {
                         steps {
                             sh 'cd Backend'  
                             sh 'echo start test'
                             sh 'ls'
                            sh 'npm run test'
                         }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dir` is a step, therefore it must be contained within `steps` block:

```
stage('build') {
    steps {
        dir("Backend") {
            sh 'pwd'
            sh 'echo start build'
            sh 'ls'
            sh 'npm install'
        }
    }
}
```